# Gridsome source-filesystem add tag description

Tags: graphql, gridsome, yaml-front-matter, gridsome-plugin, gridsome-source-filesystem

I'm using [`@gridsome/source-filesystem`](https://gridsome.org/plugins/@gridsome/source-filesystem) with this config:

```
{
  use: '@gridsome/source-filesystem',
  options: {
    typeName: 'Post',
    path: 'content/posts/**/*.md',
    refs: {
      tags: {
        typeName: 'Tag',
        create: true
      },
      author: {
        typeName: 'Author',
        create: true
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Now I want to add `description` **for one tag only**, so I created a new doc in `content/posts/my-tag.md`:

```yaml
---
title: Tag-Title
description:tag description
---
```

How can I connect this document to the `allTags` collection?

Or any other way (without [`@gridsome/source-filesystem`](https://gridsome.org/plugins/@gridsome/source-filesystem) for `Tags`, for example), to add `description` to exists `node` in `collection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just add `allTags`, you can create markdown for it.

in `gridsome.config.js`

```js
...
    {
      use: '@gridsome/source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: 'content/tags/**/*.md',
        typeName: 'Tag'
      },
    }
...
```

add file `content/tags/my-tag.md`

```
---
title: Tag-Title
description: tag description
---
```

you can explole

```
{
  allTag {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        description
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "allTag": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "******", // random hash
            "title": "Tag-Title",
            "description": "tag description"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "foo",
            "title": "foo",
            "description": ""
          }
        },
...
```

but, this is not able to connect to your `Post`.

or just added description to `Tag`, you can use `addSchemaResolvers`.
in `gridsome.server.js`

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.loadSource(async ({ addSchemaResolvers }) => {
    addSchemaResolvers({
      Tag: {
        description: {
          type: "String",
          resolve(obj) {
            if (!obj.description) {
              // coding your logic
              return "set description";
            } else {
              return obj.description;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: This seems like a good direction. I understand that logic will run whenever a property is accessed. Is it impossible to load all the information once?
That is, add information on top of the information generated from soure-filesystem?

Comment: If you don't need to create a Tag in Post, you can associate markdown files with each other. `{ typeName: 'Tag', create: false }` and add `id: your-id` to `content/tags/my-tag.md`, add `tags: ['your-id']` to `content/posts/**/*.md`. If you need a sample, I'll add another answer, just request it.

Comment: But with this way I have to create an `x-tag.md` file foe each tag in `content/posts/**/*.md`, right?
There is a trade-off here- create tags in separate files or by `post`, but there is no official way to ** creates from the post if not exists in another file**?
If no, I will mark this Q as an answer since in my question there is a limitation to not create `.md` for each tag, so the other solution will not accept.

Comment: u are right. sorry, I can't think of a better way to do it :( thx